# BadValueError: Property year must be an int or long, not a unicode

Tags: google-app-engine

I can't figure out why I'm getting this error --> "BadValueError: Property year must be an int or long, not a unicode" when I'm already using the IntegerProperty() in my Birth Class down below. I just want my page to allow the user to enter a birthday, have the information validated and then print the same birthday down below and ask is it correct.

```
import os
import webapp2
import jinja2
from google.appengine.ext import db
template_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates')
jinja_env = jinja2.Environment(loader = jinja2.FileSystemLoader(template_dir),
                           autoescape = True)
class Handler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def write(self, *a, **kw):
            self.response.out.write(*a, **kw)

    def render_str(self, template, **params):
            t = jinja_env.get_template(template)
            return t.render(params)

    def render(self, template, **kw):
            self.write(self.render_str(template, **kw))

    months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]
    def valid_month(self, month):
        months_abbvs = dict((m[:3].lower(), m) for m in self.months)
        if month:
            short_month = month[:3].lower()
            return months_abbvs.get(short_month)
    def valid_day(self, day):
        if day and day.isdigit():
            day = int(day)
            if day in range(0,32):
                return day
    def valid_year(self, year):
        if year and year.isdigit():
            year = int(year)
            if year in range(1950,2021):
                return year

class Birth(db.Model):
month = db.StringProperty(required=True)
day = db.IntegerProperty(required=True)
year = db.IntegerProperty(required=True)


class MainPage(Handler):

     def write_form(self, error="", month="", day="", year=""):
         self.render('practice.html', error=error, month=month, day=day, year=year)

     def get(self):
         self.write_form()

     def post(self):
         month = self.request.get('month')
         day = self.request.get('day')
         year = self.request.get('year')

         user_month = self.valid_month(month)
         user_day = self.valid_day(day)
         user_year = self.valid_year(year)

         if (user_month and user_day and user_year):
            a = Birth(month=month, day=day, year=year)
            a.put()
            self.redirect('/')
            birthdate = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * from Birth limit 1")
            self.render('practice.html', birthdate=birthdate)

         else:
            error="Bro, its invalid!"
            self.write_form(error, month, day, year)




app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage)], 
                          debug=True)
```

Comment: You should post the stack trace, it provides valuable information, as the line number where the error is taking place.

Comment: this is all it gives me " % (self.name, type(value).__name__))
BadValueError: Property year must be an int or long, not a unicode"

Comment: It doesn't tell me any line

Comment: My problem lies in my post function bc when I run it and then click the submit button it gives me that error, Im breaking everything down!

Comment: In your `post()` function, you are checking `year` (string) with the `valid_year()` function, which returns an `int` which you assign to `user_year`, but you are then passing your initial `year` (string) into `Birth()`, which has an `IntegerProperty()`.

Comment: Ok so I passed in user_month, user_day, and user_year and it worked!! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the statement:

```
a = Birth(month=month, day=day, year=year)
```

you're using the original *strings*, e.g, `year`, *not* the converted `int`s, e.g, `user_year`. This explains the error you're seeing.

Comment: @HozaifaAbdalla, you're welcome! Please remember to *accept* the answer (click on the checkmark outline to its left) as per normal etiquette in this site.

Comment: Ok sorry about that I'm still fairly new to stack over flow! and thank you for the help!